# Laravel Google api client get refresh token and upload files

Tags: laravel-5, google-api, guzzle

> Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request::filledHeader()

This is the error that I'm getting when I try to fetch access token with refresh token.

I have  **google/apiclient - ^2.0** and as far as I can see it works with **guzzlehttp/guzzle: ~5.3.1|~6.0**.

I used laravel socialite and made a service for google. I'm making a offline request to fetch the refresh_token from google and update the currently logged user with it.So far everything works.

When I try to create a new Instance of the Google Client and fetch the token with the refresh token I get the following error

> Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request::filledHeader()

```php
$client = new Google_Client();
        $client->refreshToken(Auth::user()->getUserInfo()->refresh_token);
$this->drive = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
```

The error is in the refreshToken. What am I missing and not doing right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend of mine found a solution for the problem. The problem was that the [`http-message`'s `MessageInterafce`](https://github.com/php-fig/http-message/blob/master/src/MessageInterface.php) was updated and the `filledHeader()` method was renamed to `hasHeader()`. After updating guzzle to `~6.0@dev` everything works fine.

```
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0@dev"
```